# Getting "misaligned address" trying to solve leetcode problem: 217. Contains Duplicate

Tags: c, hashtable

I am new to the concept of a hash table (just learned it today) so I am trying to implement it all by myself before using some sort of library or other programming language syntax to help me. The code below tries to solve the following problem: `Given an integer array nums, return true if any value appears at least twice in the array, and return false if every element is distinct.`

```c
typedef struct node{
    int n;
    struct node *next;
}
node;

int hash(int i) {
    return abs((i*2654435761)%1024);
}

void unloadBucket(node *at) {
    if(at->next != NULL) {
        unloadBucket(at->next);
    }
    free(at);
}

bool containsDuplicate(int* nums, int numsSize){
    node *table[1024];

    // Load buckets of hash table
    for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        table[i] = malloc(sizeof(node));
        table[i]->n = 0;
        table[i]->next = NULL;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++) {
        int key = hash(nums[i]);
        node *at = table[key];

        while(at->next != NULL) {
            if(at->n == nums[i])
                return true;
            else
                at = at->next;
        }

        at->n = nums[i];
        at->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
    }

    // Unload buckets
    for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        unloadBucket(table[i]);
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here is the error message that leetcode is returning to me:

```
Line 12: Char 10: runtime error: member access within misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebebe for type 'struct node', which requires 8 byte alignment [solution.c]
0xbebebebebebebebe: note: pointer points here
<memory cannot be printed>
```

Originally, i was getting the same error message at line 25, since I thought it was a memory leak problem I added the unloadBucket function that got the same error...

Comment: You'll need to dump this in a debugger and see what's going on.

Comment: `at->next = malloc(sizeof(node));` You allocated something. Did you initialize it? Next time you access that, you're treading on garbage memory.

Comment: `(i*2654435761)` probably causes undefined behaviour (signed integer overflow)

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].